GAN performance is good when using train seed but bad for unseen seed random latent space vector
I trained GAN with fixed random seed such as 42, the model good at generating high quality training real samples.
When the model is predicted using unseen seed random latent space, the generated result subjectively low quality.
Why is that? Can I say this is called Mode Collapse GAN?
